# What is the most efficent way to implement concurrency in Python?

Tags: python, concurrency, multithreading, process

In a cluster environment using Python what is the least expensive way to develop a concurrent application or what is the pro / con of the various options?

Comment: More info please, it's too difficult to discuss pros/cons without know the specific type of application, hardware available, etc.

Comment: That is meaningless. There's network overhead, CPU overhead, memory overhead, local I/O overhead, etc. Often times, these compete with each other. What you want to do depends on which you need to focus on optimizing.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. What method has the greatest CPU, which has the greatest memory, etc...

Comment: It sounds like this is more of an educational effort than something you intend on using in the future for a specific purpose. If that's the case, then I wish you well in your studies and applaud your effort to learn somthing new :) . If it isn't, I recommend you STOP what you are doing and learn the fundmentals before you piss your boss/clients off later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say Google app engine is the easiest option since you don't have to worry about all this things. But if it's a big project, it might not be the cheapest solution.

Again, it really depends on the size of your project and what you really want to do.

You need to give more details if you want to get a precise answer.

There is also a [few packages](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=cluster&submit=search) available on the python package index.

Comment: One nitpick (I'm not downvoting): we have no clue as to what the OP wants, and you admit this in your "answer." How can you recommend a package with no clue as to what the OP wants? I see this as a rampant problem on SO that I am sometimes guilty of myself.

Comment: Well yes I only gave a link to "cluster" related package.

Comment: we need a little bit more details.